# Custom 404 handling for images

Tags: 9, event-subscribers

I'm looking for a way to handle 404's on images in Drupal. I have created several subscribers, but none seem to get triggered. My first try was to create subscriber that extends `RouteSubscriberBase`. The alterRoutes method looked like:

```
protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('system.404')) {
      $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ImageRouteController::load');
    } else {
     (..)
    }
  }
```

This works perfectly for all 404's except for images (ending in .jpg or .png). This will still generate a default 404 page. It's actually a light-weight version, not the same as a 404 on a non-image non-existing page. When I debug through the Drupal code (starting in index.php) I see it goes through many steps before generating that light 404. So it does reach the Drupal code.

I found one particular interesting bit of code (which is reached when visiting a non-existing image):

```
$this->dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::EXCEPTION, $event);
```

This can be found in the `handle` method of `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel`. With that knowledge I managed to find this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2331613 . Again, it doesn't seem to work. What I have now:

my_module.services.yml:

```
my_module.exception_image_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber\ExceptionImageSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

src\EventSubscriber\ExceptionImageSubscriber.php (removed comments):

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HttpExceptionSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class ExceptionImageSubscriber extends HttpExceptionSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  protected function getHandledFormats() {
    return ['svg','jpg','gif','png','webp'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected static function getPriority() {
    return 0;
  }

  /**
   * Handles a 404 error for images
   */
  public function on404(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) {
     dd('test'); // <- not firing?!
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything, not for non-images or for images.

I start to believe the problem is that modules are not loaded when images are requested. Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The light-weight version are fast 404 pages. They are configurable in `system.performance.yml`. The configuration can be overridden in `settings.php`. The default is:

```
$config['system.performance']['fast_404']['paths'] = '/\.(?:txt|png|gif|jpe?g|css|js|ico|swf|flv|cgi|bat|pl|dll|exe|asp)$/i';
```

If you want to override this 404 handling in code your exception subscriber needs a priority >200:

```
  protected static function getPriority() {
    return 300;
  }
```

and the format has to be `html`, not the file extensions:

```
  protected function getHandledFormats() {
    return ['html'];
  }
```

For reference https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21Fast404ExceptionHtmlSubscriber.php/class/Fast404ExceptionHtmlSubscriber

Comment: So close, yet so far away :). I did come across the fast_404 option, but didn't find the solution. Thanks a lot!